# The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 720, which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 1

Tags: sql-server, connection-pooling

I have researched a lot and there is very little information especially when you see it with Failure ID = 1, which is default code.

It suddenly started appearing on our PROD servers.

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3) - 12.0.6024.0

We set default db to master for our users.

Any help or pointer in right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like too many connections. Are you ensuring your connections get disposed/closed by the client? And is there a reason you are not on the latest build, if not on a newer supported version of SQL Server?

Comment: we are in process of updating our SQL version to latest build but in the mean time would like to address this problem. We have too many applications which connects to our DB server, which will take some time to review and in the mean time how can we ensure too many connections does not cause a problem and we have checked number of connections too they were around 3500 when issue occurred normally they are around 3300 and this is not much big of a difference.